# F# NumericLiteral: FromString method

Tags: f#

Does anyone know if there is a way to *automatically* invoke the FromString method of a numeric literal in F#? I have already tried (and succeeded) with the methods FromOne, FromZero, etc but I have no idea how strings could be handled at compile time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from page 51 of the [F# language specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf):

```
xxxx<suffix>
For xxxx = 0 -> NumericLiteral<suffix>.FromZero()
For xxxx = 1 -> NumericLiteral<suffix>.FromOne()
For xxxx in the Int32 range -> NumericLiteral<suffix>.FromInt32(xxxx)
For xxxx in the Int64 range -> NumericLiteral<suffix>.FromInt64(xxxx)
For other numbers -> NumericLiteral<suffix>.FromString("xxxx")
```

That means, only when the first 4 are not satisfied, `FromString` is called. Also, `xxxx` must be digits with signs, you cannot use other alphabeta set for xxxx.

Comment: What a pity! And I was already wondering about my next inline language :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's intended for numbers bigger than Int64.MaxValue.